# Auto connect VPN script on linux at boot

Tags: bash, vpn, boot

I'm writing a bash script on linux to run at each boot.
This script serves to connect automatically on a surfshark vpn server at boot.

This is my script:

```
#! /bin/bash 
echo "1"|sudo surfshark-vpn attack
```

I use this code to add administrator property to my script:

```
sudo chmod +x scriptVPN.sh
```

I use different guide to run this script on boot but none of these work.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can create a systemd unit file which will accomplish the task  at boot.

Answer (score 0):

Update your shell script to:

`#! /bin/bash echo -e "\n" | sudo surfshark-vpn attack`

**echo -e** (with -e) allows the command **echo** to interpret backslash escapes i.e. it will press 'enter' after **sudo surfshark-vpn attack**

Comment: Adding a few lines of explanation will make this an answer. Right now it is just a comment with a bit of bash command in it.